# Implementing Scroll View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

Im trying to make a scroll on my app which halfway works. When I rum the program, my scroll scrolls but not all the way down. It just stops and I don't know how to adjust it. The scroll view is the same size as the view, but the view on top of the scroll is bigger. I tried some code that I found online, but it just keeps saying "expected declaration." Any ideas on how to implement this? This is on swift.

import UIKit

class medicationsViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var scroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!


scroll.userInteractionEnabled = true
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,1100)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the scroll changes inside of some method. Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 scroll.userInteractionEnabled = true
 scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,1100) 
}
```